# How to use angular selector 2 times but component initialize one time?

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML

```
 <exchange></exchange>
 <exchange></exchange>
```

TS

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'exchange',
          templateUrl: 'exchange.component.html',

        })
        export class ExchangeComponent implements OnInit {
           ngOnInit() {
              interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
              console.log(x)});
           }
        }
```

I call the component twice but I don't want the interval to run twice every 10 seconds. 
I want it to work only once

Comment: You could try putting the logic in service

Comment: You can't manage it from the component itself, because the component don't know how many times it will be called. As @MePo said, you should use a service to store a boolean like `isFirstCall = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something simple like this:

In a service file store a variable to do something based on its value.

```
shouldSubscribe: boolean = false;
```

In your component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
 if(!this.someService.shouldSubscribe) {
    interval(10000).subscribe(x => {console.log(x)});
 } else {
    this.someService.shouldSubscribe = true;
 }     
}
```

An **alternative** approach would be to pass property to one instance of your component and use that as a check:

```
<exchange [shouldSubscribe]="true"></exchange>
<exchange></exchange>
```

In component.ts:

```
@Input() shouldSubscribe: boolean;
```

and inside the lifecycle hook:

```
if(this.shouldSubscribe) {
// do want you want
}
```

In your question, you asked how to prevent the component from initializing again you can't do that(If you skip writing `ngOnInit` it'll execute by default because it's a lifecycle hook).